# Need to get mouse x and y coordinates from image and on click add them to a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

[this is what i have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuewL.png)
this shows the image and table design that i have so far. I dont know how to get the coordinates from the mouse click on the image

I am using visual studio(using asp.net with C#) to create a site that tracks the shots on a hockey net. I have an image of a hockey net and a table below it, the user needs to click on the image and the coordinates of the mouse should be inserted into the table. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the mouse coordinates inserted into the table when the mouse is clicked.

If anyone has an example of this or something similar or can find a tutorial that may help it would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and haven't been able to find anything to help for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What kind of table are you talking about?

Comment: i have a grid view table set up with the delete button for each row so you can remove an unwanted shot

Comment: Which part are you trying to figure out? Can you get the mouse coordinates from a click on the image? What does your database table look like? Show us the relevant parts of your code, and tell us what isn't working. We're not just going to write it for you.

Comment: Im not looking for it to be done for me, thats what im looking for help for, getting the coordinates from the mouse click, im new to using visual basic this is the first site i am trying to create and im adding a image to show what it looks like so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event handler to the container which is displaying the image.  The Winforms example below shows how to add the mouse click event and display the x and y coordinates.  Just make sure you use the MouseClick and not the Click event.

> ```
> Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
>     MsgBox("X = " And e.X And " Y = " And e.Y)
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: He did state using asp.net with C#